# How to call a non-void method from a trigger?

Tags: trigger, method

I have a trigger which is calling several non-void methods of apex classes.But I always get 'null' as a return value from these methods. Can someone explain why is this happening? I tried using the static key-word too, but it is showing the same result, 'null'. 
Following is the code snippet I am using to call class methods from trigger:

```
String[] operations=cd.CustBusinessPro__Operations__c.split(',');
          System.debug('splitted operations>>>>'+operations);
          for(String str:operations)
          { 
              if(str == ' PAN_Check')
             { system.debug('inside  pan');
               PAN_Check pan = new PAN_Check();
              result = Pan.PanCheck(app.CustBusinessPro__PAN__c,app.CustBusinessPro__Last_Name__c);
              system.debug('>>>>>>>>returned value'+result);

             }
             else if(str == 'De_Dup')
             {
                system.debug('inside de_dup');
                De_Dup d = new De_Dup();
                d.DeDup(app.CustBusinessPro__PAN__c,app.CustBusinessPro__Type_of_Loan__c);
             }
             else if(str == ' CIBIL Verification')
             {
              system.debug('inside cibil');
              CIBILVerification cibil=new CIBILVerification();
              cibil.CIBILCheck(app.CustBusinessPro__CIBIL_Score__c);
             }
             else if(str == ' Eligibility Verification')
             {
             system.debug('inside eligibilty');
             EligibilityVerification elig=new EligibilityVerification();
             elig.EligibilityCheck(app.CustBusinessPro__Salary__c,app.CustBusinessPro__Type_of_Loan__c,app.CustBusinessPro__Loan_Amount__c);
             }
             else if(str == ' EMI Verification')
             {
                system.debug('inside EMI');
                EMI_Calculation emi = new  EMI_Calculation();
                emi.EMICalculation(app.CustBusinessPro__Loan_Amount__c,app.CustBusinessPro__Loan_Tenure__c);
             }
             else if(str == ' NegativeAreaCheck')
             {
               system.debug('inside NAC');
               NegativeAreaCheck NAC = new NegativeAreaCheck();
               NAC.PincodeCheck(app.CustBusinessPro__Postal_Code__c);
             }
          }

        }
        else
        {
          System.debug('Criteria not satisfied');
        }
```

And this is the pan_check class:

```
public with sharing class PAN_Check{

public CustBusinessPro__Applicant__c applicant{get;set;}

String panCard{get;set;}
String LastName{get;set;}
String PanFormat{get;set;}

public PAN_Check(){

    applicant = new CustBusinessPro__Applicant__c();
    PanFormat = '[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}'; //Definition of format of PAN consisting of 5 letters in the start followed by 4 numbers and again a letter. 


}



public  Boolean PanCheck(String panCardNo,String lname){

    Boolean flag;
    LastName = lname;
    System.debug('------'+lname);

    panCard = panCardNo;
    System.debug('----------------------' + panCard);

    //Checking the PAN number against the defined format. 
    pattern MyPattern = pattern.compile(PanFormat);
    matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(panCardNo);

    //for splitting the characters of PAN and the last name of the applicant. 
    string[] chars = panCardNo.split('');
    string[] chars1 = lname.split('');

    //checking if the 5th character of the PAN is equal to the 1st character of last name. 
    if(MyMatcher.matches()){   

        if(chars[4] == chars1[0]){

            //if its equal PAN check passed or else failed. 
            System.debug(panCard + '---------------PAN Check passed!!'); 
            flag=true; 
        }

    }

    else{

        System.debug(panCard + '---------------PAN Check failed!!');
        flag=false;

    }

    insert new Account(Name='MyPANCheck');
    return flag;
}

}
```

Comment: is it even getting into the if statement of ` if(MyMatcher.matches()){   ` Does it show the debug statement within the if statements?

Comment: Yes the debug statements are generated

Comment: Your declaration `Boolean flag;` leaves that value `null` if the field is not set in the if/else logic later in the method. So if you want the method to return `false` if it isn't set to a value in the if/else logic, initialise it where you declare it `Boolean flag = false;'.

Comment: Yes as Prady pointed out, Its not getting inside the if/else part. But it was working fine when executed alone!

Comment: What do you mean by executed alone? Here is what could be happening  ` if(MyMatcher.matches()){ ` is returning true and it goes into the if statement and thenchecks if(chars[4] == chars1[0]){ . If this statement returns false then the flag is null. You are not setting the value of Flag if this statement is false

Comment: Okay, When I am entering a correct pan no. it is going inside the if part, but when I am entering a incorrect pan number, it does not go inside the else part!

Comment: Okay that worked! Thankyou so much Prady and Kieth C

Comment: Glad i could be of help

Answer (score 1):

The issue looks to me with you not setting the value of flag in the else statement for `if(chars[4] == chars1[0]){`

If the code execution does not satisfy the this `if` statement, then it exits out without setting any value for flag. You need to set the value of Flag in the else statement.